# After rewriting URL page not found

Tags: url-rewriting, redirects, htaccess, apache, mod-rewrite

I want to rewrite my current URL that is

```
http://localhost/sitename/landing-page/?from=Algeria&to=Afghanistan&submit=Submit
```

to `http://localhost/sitename/removals-from-Algeria-to-Afghanistan`
I have written the rewrite rule for this.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /([^/]+)/landing-page/?\?(from)=([^&]+)&(to)=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/removals-%2-%3-%4-%5? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^removals-from-([^-]+)-to-([^-]+)$ /removalscenter/landing-page/?from=$1&to=$2&submit=Submit [L]
```

My htaccess code is..

```
 # BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /removalscenter/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /([^/]+)/landing-page/?\?(from)=([^&]+)&(to)=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/removals-%2-%3-%4-%5? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^removals-from-([^-]+)-to-([^-]+)$ /removalscenter/landing-page/?from=$1&to=$2&submit=Submit [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /removalscenter/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Now the link is changed.. but it is giving page not found error..

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming (looking at your `RewriteRule` pattern) that this .htaccess file is located in the `/removalscenter` directory? (Although the first couple of directives are generic, allowing for `<sitename>`, the remaining directives appear to be hardcoded?)

By setting a `RewriteBase` directive, you don't need to specify the full path for the `RewriteRule` *substitutions* - that is the reason for using `RewriteBase`. You can keep the `RewriteRule` substitution as relative (simplifying the rules) . For example:

> `RewriteRule . /removalscenter/index.php [L]`

Can simply be:

```
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

> `http://localhost/sitename/landing-page/?from=Algeria&to=Afghanistan&submit=Submit`

Your example URL does not look like the full URL. It's missing the index document eg. `index.php`. If you don't explicitly state this then mod_dir will need to "fix it", resulting an additional rewrite which might be causing problems. So, this should be something like:

```
http://localhost/sitename/landing-page/index.php?from=Algeria&to=Afghanistan&submit=Submit
```

Likewise, the trailing slash should not be optional in your `RewriteCond` directive.

In order to debug the 404 further, try temporarily changing the *internal rewrite* to a temporary (302) *external redirect* by adding an `R` flag. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^removals-from-([^-]+)-to-([^-]+)$ landing-page/index.php?from=$1&to=$2&submit=Submit [L,R]
```

Does it redirect? What does it redirect to?